# How to calculate the percentage of the times that the two vectors are increasing or decreasing together

Tags: r

I want to write a function to compare the increment of two vectors in R.  The functions returns the percentage of the times that the two vectors are increasing or decreasing together.

I wrote the following function and I tested that with vectors:

```
x=c(1,3,5,6,7)
y=c(1,5,6,8,7)
```

The result should be 0.75 but when I call `correl(x,y)` there is an error

```
Error in if ...missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any help?

```
correl<-function(x,y){ 
  count = c()
  for (i in 1:length(x))
    if((((y[i+1]-y[i]) > 0) && ((x[i+1]-x[i]) > 0)) || (((y[i+1]-y[i]) < 0) && ((x[i+1]-x[i]) < 0))) 
      count <- union(count, c(i))
  print(length(count) / length(x)-1)
}
```

Comment: What happens to `i+1` when `i=length(x)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd rather vectorize the function, for example this way :

```
diffx <- diff(x)
diffy <- diff(y)
sum(sign(diffx)==sign(diffy)) / length(diffx)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very helpful. This way is much better!

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop ends at `length(x)`, and then you have `y[i+1]` which doesn't contain a value. You should end the loop on `length(x-1)`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried with length(x)-1 but I had the same error. Using diff function as proposed form juba the problem solved